Form input field outline and placeholder is not working in Angular Material 16
<p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

It seems like you might be encountering an issue with your Angular Material input field. To create an input field with an outline and a placeholder using Angular Material 16, you can use the following code:
         <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
              <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

Make sure you have imported the necessary Angular Material modules and styles in your application. If you're still experiencing issues, double-check your Angular Material version and the documentation to ensure compatibility.

issue not reproducible stackblitz compare you code with stackblitz, check the imports as chatgpt said
